# Android- Encode source code to be safe from reverse engineering

Tags: android, security, encode

I made an Application which made a connection to an FTP Server, using username and password.
Now i'm asking my self if it's possible to encrypt my Source code, so that it's not possible to read it after making an .apk?
otherwise "hackers" would be able to get my password and username.

Staromir

Comment: No that is not possible. You can make reverse engineering harder by obfuscating your code, but that's it. It's impossible to prevent reverse engineering. If they really want your username and password they can get it. You have to consider other solutions if you want your username and password to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, encrypt your strings so that they are not in plain text visible when one inspects the code. Use encryption / decryption methods to load the plain text into memory rather than hard code it.

Next take a look at [proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) which obfuscates code. This should make it harder (but not impossible!) for "hackers" to get an understanding of your code.